# Message Type COPRAR_ITG12 is not allowed as part of the Agreement.

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

I have an integration that sends EDI file to destination but in Agreement i get such an error:

> There was a failure executing the send pipeline:
>   "EdiLogPipeline.SendEdiLogPipeline, EdiLogPipeline, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b443f8c1ff13f7f0" Source:
>   "LogAssemblerComponent" Send Port: "XXX_SendPort" URI: "Destination"
>   Reason: Message Type COPRAR_ITG12 is not allowed as part of the
>   Agreement.

I tried too many things but nothing works.

In my map file My source file  is custom XML file and destination file EFACT_D95B_COPRAR_ITG12. When I defined parties UNH2.5 segment is set to ITG12. Although i defined all of the other rules correctly, it still did not work.

When I searched default EDI schemas in Biztalk path, EFACT_D95B_COPRAR_ITG12 is not one of the default schemas. So Biztalk does not accept this schema. Is there any solution for this problem?

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Message Type COPRAR_ITG12 is not allowed as part of the Agreement" this message give us a useful information which is **`message type is not allowed`**.  My source file's root name was "EFACT_D95B_COPRAR_ITG12"but Biztalk does not allow this naming for EDI files. We have to use Microsoft's default files' names and root names. I changed my source file name and root name to "EFACT_D95B_COPRAR". And this solution works for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that is either not on the list of allowed message types or is on the list of disallowed message types.

On the Agreement, You->Them Tab, Transaction Set List.  You can configure either a Support or Exclude list.

Comment: I tried to add some restrictions and allow this type of files. In the UNH2.5 segment I allowed ITG12 but it still gives same error.

Comment: Try an empty Exclude list first and go from there.  Also, make sure you're not unintentionally using the Fallback Settings by disabling them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I tried your suggestion but now I am getting such an error: There was a failure executing the send pipeline: "EdiLogPipeline.SendEdiLogPipeline, EdiLogPipeline, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b443f8c1ff13f7f0" Source: "LogAssemblerComponent" Send Port: "SendEDIFTP" URI: "SourceFile" Reason: The value MY PROFILE is invalid according to UNOA Char Set.  What should I need to do?

Comment: The [space] is the only odd character.  I don't know what the LogAssemblerComponent is, that's not part of BizTalk.